# jquery button value to title

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a lot buttons all over a site with a value (the text of the button) and each has, for example a bootstrap class of '.btn-default':

```
<input type="button" value="Clear" class="form-control input-sm btn-default" onclick="doingSomethingElseEtc();">
```

How might I use jQuery to get the value of the button and bind it to a title attribute to each button, so if you moused over the button, you'd get the default browser tooltip containing the string from the button value, etc..?

For example, just to get the gist of what I'm asking:

```
$('.btn-default').attr('title', $(".btn-default").val());
```

I'm trying to touch the code as little as possible, etc..

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use each to iterate each button and set the titles.

```
$('.btn-default').each(function(i,obj){
    $(obj).attr('title', $(obj).val());
});
```

Comment: Threw it into $(document).ready, works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No need for any arguments, or variables, or other whatzit. :-)

```
$('.btn-default').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).val());
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yj39c863/)

Answer (score 1):

Your idea will work too, if you're adding a function to the `attr` like this:

```
$('.btn-default').attr('title', function() {
    //console.log($(this).val(), $(this).text());
    return $(this).val() || $(this).text();
});
```

This will add to each button with class `btn-default` the title attribute.
I think it's also good to get the text because your button could be defined with `input value=".."` or with `<button>text</button>`

Please have a look at the demo below and in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/vb9849yr/).

```js
$('.btn-default').attr('title', function() {
  //console.log($(this).val(), $(this).text());
  return $(this).val() || $(this).text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Clear" class="form-control input-sm btn-default" onclick="doingSomethingElseEtc();">
<button class="btn-default">test1</button>
<button class="btn-default">test2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read the value of a collection of elements, jQuery only returns the value of the first one in the set. So you need to iterate over all of them and set the title on each one.

```
$('.btn-default').each( function () {
   var elem = $(this);
   elem.attr('title', elem.val());
});
```

Downside to this is if there is a lot of elements, it will be slow. Also you need to do this on document ready.